# How to update google drive file permissions using REST API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I tried to update google drive file permission, i.e tried to give new role. But it throwing an exception. Here is the sample code.

```
Permission content = new Permission();
permission.setRole("Reader");
permission.setType("user");
permission.setEmailAddress("x@gmail.com");
driveService.permissions().update(fileId, permissionId, permission).queue(batch, callback);
```

For this sample code I got Json exception as follows

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "fieldNotWritable",
    "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
 }
}
```

Can some help me, how to resolve this?

Comment: How this is possible in Java Drive REST API V3?

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake, i.e added user email address and type also in request apart from user new role. But these two fields are not overridable in Drive REST API v3. So I got exception. Corrected sample code is as foillows

```
Permission content = new Permission();
content.setId(id_of_the_file);
content.setRole("Reader");
driveService.permissions().update(fileId, permissionId, permission).setFields("role").execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have permission first from the API. You're missing this line:

Permission permission = service.permissions().get(
fileId, permissionId).execute();

like:

```
public class MyClass {

// ...

/**
* Update a permission's role.
*
* @param service Drive API service instance.
* @param fileId ID of the file to update permission for.
* @param permissionId ID of the permission to update.
* @param newRole The value "owner", "writer" or "reader".
* @return The updated permission if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
*/
private static Permission updatePermission(Drive service, String fileId,
String permissionId, String newRole) {

    try {
        // First retrieve the permission from the API.
        Permission permission = service.permissions().get(fileId, permissionId).execute();

        permission.setRole(newRole);

        return service.permissions().update(fileId, permissionId, permission).execute();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }

    return null;

}

// ...

}
```

More details in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update#examples).

Comment: This is working fine in Drive REST API V2, but not in V3. Is there any alternative to update permissions in V3?